# How to unit test "console.readLine" for invalid input?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am scratching my head on this little problem.

I have this line and 3 other similar ones in a method

```
try
{
    int PhoneIMEINumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}

{
catch(Exception)
{
    return null;
}
```

If the user enters "abcd" for input, this throws an exception and I can catch it and show an error message.

But how do I make a unit test for this? I can't simulate console input from the unit test ofcourse and I want to check from my unit test if a null was returned.

Thank you

Comment: You should probably not unit test the Console, but rather test the business rules.

Comment: One of the great benefits of unit testing is that it makes you re-evaluate your design. You should do that now and refactor your code. Currently the ReadLine is much too tightly coupled to the business/validation code.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Hank, I have a scenario where I'd like to test a method that analyzes a file on my computer which is specified by a user via `Console.ReadLine()`. How should this be handled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like the two comments posted.  I would consider refactoring your code to look something more like

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();

try
{
    int PhoneIMEINumber = parse_input(input); 
}
catch(Exception)
{
    return null;
}
```

and then you'd have a function

```
public int parse_input(string input)
{
    return int.Parse(input);
}
```

THEN you'd write a unit test for the `parse_input` function.  The example code seems quite trivial though and it is hard to justify writing a unit test around a wrapper function for int.Parse(), but I'm assuming that your parsing might get more complicated in the future.

Comment: Super...this is so simple...just what I needed +1

Comment: +1 since you are actually the only one that separated business logic from infrastructure. All the other answers just tried to abstract away the console when it's not really relevant when validating the IMEI number.

Comment: @jgauffin Well the OP specifically asked how to Unit Test the `Console` although I like this approach a lot more.

Comment: @Romoku: It's not always that the OPs know what they really want ;)

Answer (score 10):

If you want to Unit Test the `Console` then you'll probably need to create a wrapper interface.

```
public interface IConsole
{
    string ReadLine();
}

public class ConsoleWrapper : IConsole
{
    public string ReadLine()
    {
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This way you can create a Stub/Fake to test your business rules.

```
public class TestableConsole : IConsole
{
    private readonly string _output;

    public TestableConsole(string output)
    {
        _output = output;
    }

    public string ReadLine()
    {
        return _output;
    }
}
```

Inside the test:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private readonly IConsole _console;

    public TestClass(IConsole console)
    {
        _console = console;
    }

    public void RunBusinessRules()
    {
        int value;
        if(!int.TryParse(_console.ReadLine(), out value)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("User input was not valid");
        }
    }
}

[Test]
public void TestGettingInput()
{
    var console = new TestableConsole("abc");

    var classObject = new TestClass(console);

    Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => classObject.RunBusinessRules());
}
```

I would go with trying to avoid Unit Testing the `Console` and taking a dependency on it.

Comment: ++ Classic Dependency Injection

Comment: thanks...very detailed answer, super!! +1. Al W's solution was a bit more appropriate for my solution.

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't recommend using this solution unless you have a specific need for it.

Answer (score 9):

You can set `Console.In` to a given text reader using [SetIn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setin.aspx):

```
var sr = new StringReader("Invalid int");
Console.SetIn(sr);

int? parsed = MethodUnderTest();
Assert.IsNull(parsed);
```

Comment: This is what I thought of first, too. I'm confused why this answer has so few upvotes? Does this not work?

Comment: I am writing test cases for hello-world like apps that use the console and this is exactly what I want.  Example: Enter your Name validate that "Hello <Name>" is returned.  Thanks.

Comment: using Console.SetIn is the most practical answer. You can mock the TextReader passed and verify the ReadLine call count too.

Answer (score 0):

To unit test a code, that piece of code needs to be testable.

To unit test a method, what we do is pass in some known input and check it is returning expected result or if we are having correct side effect.

Now if you directly take your input inside your method, it is not very testable. It has two parts, reading the input and processing it. If the assert in your test fails, you don't know which step failed. Unit test should be aimed towards testing a unit or single responsibilty of a code.

To make it testable, read the input in main method and pass it to another method for processing (also common notion of object oriented programming), and test the second method with known parameters.